# OPENSSL Rand DRBG Andorid crashed when is used many times: A/libc: Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS)

Tags: android, c++, openssl, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm trying the use the OpenSSL Rand library with DRBG in an android app, this library is implemented in native code of NDK. At starting, the OpenSSL works fine but in many times the app crashed and don't show any throw message. Here is the only error message that showwing:

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 1 (BUS_ADRALN), fault addr 0xb1aedca6f2d64adf in tid 22101 (RenderThread), pid 22075 (android.example)
```

My code is the follow:

**libnative.cpp**

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <openssl/rand_drbg.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <future>

#ifndef TAG
#define TAG "OpenSslApi"
#endif

#ifndef DEFAULT_VALUE_ERROR
#define DEFAULT_VALUE_ERROR 0
#endif

void thread_handler(union sigval sv) {}

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_android_random_OpenSslApi_initDrbgRandom(
  JNIEnv * env,
  jclass clazz) {
  RAND_DRBG * randDrbgInstance = RAND_DRBG_new(NID_aes_256_ctr, RAND_DRBG_FLAG_CTR_NO_DF, nullptr);
  RAND_DRBG_instantiate(randDrbgInstance, nullptr, 0);
  RAND_DRBG_set_reseed_time_interval(randDrbgInstance, 0);
  RAND_DRBG_set_reseed_interval(randDrbgInstance, 0);
}

std::pair < jint * , jint > generateRandomIntDrbg(jint * secureRandom, jint sizeKey) {
  jint myStatus = RAND_DRBG_bytes(
    RAND_DRBG_get0_public(),
    (unsigned char * ) secureRandom,
    sizeKey * sizeof(int)
  );
  return std::make_pair(secureRandom, myStatus);
}

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_com_android_random_OpenSslApi_intDrbgGenerateSecureRandom(
  JNIEnv * env,
  jclass clazz,
  jintArray empty_array,
  jint size_key) {

  struct sigevent sev {};
  timer_t timerid;
  memset( & sev, 0, sizeof(sev));
  sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
  sev.sigev_notify_function = & thread_handler;
  sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = & timerid;
  timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, & sev, & timerid);

  JavaVM * javaVm = nullptr;
  env -> GetJavaVM( & javaVm);
  javaVm -> AttachCurrentThread( & env, (void ** ) & env);

  jintArray array = env -> NewIntArray(size_key);
  if (array == nullptr) {
    return DEFAULT_VALUE_ERROR;
  }
  jint * secureRandomIntArray = env -> GetIntArrayElements(array, nullptr);
  if (secureRandomIntArray == nullptr) {
    return DEFAULT_VALUE_ERROR;
  }
  std::future < std::pair < jint * , jint >> futureIntRandom = std::async (generateRandomIntDrbg, secureRandomIntArray, size_key);
  std::pair < jint * , jint > result = futureIntRandom.get();
  jint * resultSecureRandom = std::get < jint * > (result);
  if (resultSecureRandom == nullptr) {
    return DEFAULT_VALUE_ERROR;
  }
  memcpy(secureRandomIntArray, empty_array, size_key);
  env -> ReleaseIntArrayElements(empty_array, secureRandomIntArray, 0);
  return std::get < jint > (result);
}
```

OpenSslApi.java

```
static {
      System.loadLibrary("libnative");
}

public OpenSslApi() {
      initDrbgRandom();
}

public static native void initDrbgRandom();

public static native int intDrbgGenerateSecureRandom(
            int[] emptyArray,
            final int sizeKey
    );
```

Thanks for either suggestions about the solution of this error.

Comment: Thank you for participating in SO.

It is not visible what you have done so far to figure out what the root cause is.

You write: "It crashes". Please, provide more information, in particular:
- What have you already tried (e.g. debugger)?
- What makes you think that your code should work?
- What is you setup / development environment?

Comment: `memcpy(secureRandomIntArray, empty_array, size_key);` <-- You can't `memcpy` from a `jintArray`. And even if you could, why are you trying to copy **from** something called `empty_array`? Shouldn't that be the destination?

Comment: Also, `env -> ReleaseIntArrayElements(empty_array, secureRandomIntArray, 0);` looks wrong. Did you mean to use `array` instead of `empty_array`?

Comment: @JörgBrüggmann Its crash and the unique error line is the first.

Comment: So, Understood about memcpy, @Michael what do you made to pass the random array to the Java class?

Comment: @Michael The ReleaseIntArrayElements() is used to pass the completed array to Java

Comment: You shouldn't call `ReleaseIntArrayElements` on something that you haven't called `GetIntArrayElements` on. If you want to both read and write from/to a Java array, then use `GetIntArrayElements` and `ReleaseIntArrayElements`. If you just want to write to it you can use `SetIntArrayRegion` instead.

Comment: Ok. I get the other error `A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x30a9702d1eb2ad9d in tid 24691 (os.android.app), pid 24691 (os.android.app)`